# install SQL Server 2008 R2 on Chinese Vista fails: Checks if existing performance counter registry hive is consistent

Tags: sql-server, windows-vista, sql-server-2008-r2

> PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck
>
> Checks if existing performance counter
>   registry hive is consistent.
>
> Failed The performance counter
>   registry hive is corrupted. To
>   continue, you must repair the
>   performance counter registry hive. For
>   more information, see
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956.

The link totally doesn't help.  Googled several solutions, but none of them work.  Any idea??  Thanks!

Comment: Apparently you can invoke setup with an argument to prevent this check. I'm not necessarily saying you should, but it's `setup.exe /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck`, if you want it.

Comment: I tried with the downloaded SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck , doesn't work. :(

Comment: oh got it: Downloads\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU>setup.exe /ACTION=install /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck works! please answer me below and i can mark you correct

Comment: OMFG what a horrible experience. How can MS let this pass QA?  Damn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
setup.exe /ACTION=install /SKIPRULES=PerfMonCounterNotCorruptedCheck
```

to bypass that check